# How to test a new Facebook messenger App on local device

Tags: android, facebook

I have created an sample app for android, this app has integration with the new Messenger Platform.
I don't know how to test it on my device, and get the feature of the app visible in the Facebook messenger installed on my device? 
I have installed my app on my device but I don't see it listed in the Facebook messenger app.

Thank you

Comment: You can't. Listed in Facebook messenger requires that your app gets approved